# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression(error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, treeview, cytoscape.js

```js
let a=50, b=150; 
let elements= [ { data: { id: 'root ', label: 'SANIANJUM' }, position: { x: a, y: b } }, ]; let username = "SANIANJUM"; 
elements.push({ data: { id: 'two', label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 150, y: 100 } },) 
elements.push({ data: { source: 'one', target: 'two', label: 'Edge from Node1 to Node2' } },);
```

//can't push to my elements array
![Using async to fetch data here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3R7O.png

Comment: Do you have more context? Just an image, suspected error and code isn't gonna cut it. The code shown doesn't look likely to be the source of the error anyways.

Comment: Please add some more details i.e. error message/stack trace and complete code from where you are getting an error.

Comment: Unable to push to my elements ayyay , throws this error

Answer (score 0):

The React.js error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" occurs when we forget to return a value from a function. To solve the error, make sure to explicitly use a return statement or implicitly return using an arrow function.

[image: Here is the screenshot of issue]

Comment: return <CytoscapeComponent elements={elements} style={ { width: '1000px', height: '1000px' } } />;

returnig this at the end of function call

Comment: this error is coming from the function which you are using just below "elements.push({ data: { source: 'one', target: 'two', label: 'Edge from Node1 to Node2' } },);"

Not when you are pushing an element - so what ever you are returning from the function assign that to any variable/const - then use it.

Comment: (async () =>{
        const repositoriesResponse = await octokit.request("GET /user/repos");
       })();
// using async to fetch repositories of my github - using arrow function to return this